# Create drawable from bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

ALL,

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23054261/creating-iphone-like-badge-notification-on-android) I need to make a drawable out of my bitmap. But when I tried to use:

```
 Drawable d = new Drawable( my_bmp);
```

it shows that this constructor is deprecated in favour of:

```
 Drawable(Bitmap bmp, int resourceId)
```

How else I can make a drawable out of bitmap?

Thank you.

Comment: can you try this `Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(res, bmp);` ?

Comment: @SimplePlan, as I wrote in the original thread, bitmap comes from the cloud, not resource.

Comment: then you have to download that image from cloud and then load as Drawable.

Comment: @SimplePlan, yes, the image is loaded as Bitmap. The problem is - convert to Drawable. Can you give some code?

Comment: ok wait ill post my answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50662/discussion-between-simple-plan-and-igor)

Answer (score 26):

You can use

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), my_bmp);
```

> A Drawable that wraps a bitmap and can be tiled, stretched, or
>   aligned. You can create a BitmapDrawable from a file path, an input
>   stream, through XML inflation, or from a Bitmap object.

`BitmapDrawable(Resources res, Bitmap bitmap)`

> Create drawable from a bitmap, setting initial target density based on
>   the display metrics of the resources.

Also look a the public constructors @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html

Comment: you answer tells me you didn't look at the original post. ;-) I am not loading my bitmap from the resources. I am getting the bitmap as the photo from the cloud. Therefore I cannot use resource references in that code. Any other idea?

Comment: @Igor you never mentioned that in your post. its not my fault.

Comment: I did however, referenced a link to my original question where this requirement was mentioned. Like I said - you didn't look. ;-)

Comment: @Igor you could have mentioned that in your post. you din't also posting links to external source is not good as not many will look a the same :)

Comment: @Igor did you even check at the link i posted?? first download the bitmap then use `BitmapDrawable(Resources res, String filepath)` filepath is the path of the bitmap

Answer (score 3):

try this to load `Bitmap` as `Bitmap Drawable`

Create `ImgDrawableFromFile(Resources res, String file_name)` like below

```
Drawable d = null;

    public Drawable ImgDrawableFromFile(Resources res, String file_name) {

        myBitmap = null;
        File imgFile = new File(
                "/data/data/yourpkgname/app_my_sub_dir/images/" + file_name);
        if (imgFile.exists()) {

            myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

            if (myBitmap != null) {
                d = new BitmapDrawable(res, myBitmap);
                return d;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Now called this function like

```
img.setBackgroundDrawable(ImgDrawableFromFile(getResources(), "1.jpg")); // pass your saved file name as second argument
```

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party but I see a clear misunderstanding. The answers provided are indeed correct:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
```

In this case `getResources()` is a method available in the `Context` or `Activity` and is only used to find out the screen density and adjust the Drawable accordingly.

So Igor, even if you are loading the image from the cloud, you can still call getResources().

Happy coding

Answer (score 2):

`BitmapDrawable(Bitmap bitmap)` constructor has been `deprecated`

you can use

```
Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

[source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html)

Comment: @Igor Get the bitmpa from the cloud: `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());`

Answer (score 0):

you can use the BitmapDrawable class to get a Drawable from a bitmap

[Bitmap Drawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) reference

Comment: Well, I can't. I am not using resources, bitmap (photo) comes from the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If Mauro Banze was late to the party then I don't really know what I'm still doing here. But for the ones that come here desperately looking for a solution, here is what I did:

I stumbled over somewhat the same issue when bringing a Project from JavaFX to Android. I wanted to reuse most of my "data" classes which only manage and provide my data and have no affect on the UI.

**Enough story telling, here we go:**

*Problem:*

- At some point we need a `Drawable`to get out Bitmap on the screen.
- We want to download (from the cloud, the internet, or wherever) this Bitmap and save it for later usage as a `Drawable`
- We can't do that in a non-`Context` or non-`Activity` class, as we need the `Resources`.

So why don't we just save it as a `Bitmap` until we need it to be drawn (which certainly will happen in a `Context` or `Activity` class).

I have created a class called `BitmapImage`. It looks like this:

```
public class BitmapImage {

private final Bitmap bitmap;

public BitmapImage (Bitmap bitmap) {
    this.bitmap = bitmap;
}


public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}

public Drawable getDrawable(Resources res) {
    return new BitmapDrawable(res,getBitmap());
}
```

This *very* simple class "saves" the Bitmap. Thus, rather then working with a `Drawable` you work with the `BitmapImage` until you really desperately need the `Drawable`.

At that point, you should be in your `Activity` or `Context` and there you can call `Drawable foo = anyBitmapImage.getDrawable(getResource())`.