# Remotely updating or rendering a user interface

Tags: android, xml, xml-rpc, asmack

I m trying to develop a mobile app which can render xml sent from backend to the client android app.

for example: a simple form for cafe / hotel reservation. As long as a new xml pushed into the client app , the new interface should re-draw/render .

For that i have been trying to learn a similar application [here](https://github.com/rogerthat-platform/rogerthat-android-client/tree/master/lib/src/asmack) 
But , i didnt undertand how its possible . any enlightenment please.

example app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobicage.rogerth.at&hl=en

Comment: no. you are missing the compiling, so the layout `xml` won't work.

Comment: can you take a look at this app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobicage.rogerth.at&hl=en

Comment: sorry this app seems very complex, but less introduction.

Comment: Refer this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43831009/1468093